# Como limitar a quantidade de linhas após ordenação do datatable vb.net/C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, datatable

Como faço para limitar a quantidade de linhas em uma datagrid após o DefaultView.Sort

Segue o código:

```
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(MySQL, Conexao)
        dt = New DataTable("Pedidos")
        da.Fill(dt)
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Data Desc"
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Quero limitar a quantidade de linhas após o SORT, pq assim o sistema já ordenou na ordem que quero.

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar Linq, provavelmente da seguinte forma: `dt.AsEnumerable().Take(10)`.